# Set timezone to display last modified information from a directory

Tags: php

```
$headers = array("File Name", "Size", "Type", "Modified") ; 
$width = array(20, 11, 20, 11) ;                        

$info ; 

print_header() ;
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
  file_info($filename) ;
  print_file_info() ;
}
exit(0) ;

function file_info($name) {
  global $info ;                
    $info[0] = $name ;          
    $info[1] = filesize($name) ;  
    $info[2] = filetype($name);                            
    $info[3] = date($name);
}
```

Require help in setting the timezone to display the date and time under the modified section in the array "$info[3] = date($name);". I believe "date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London')" is meants to be used to set the timezone however am unsure where to input that line. It should display in the format 'Oct 20 2015 09:34' and my code seems to execute the code in the format 'f28MondayEu'.

Comment: Use it before calling any function that needs to display the time.

Comment: `date($name)` isn't right. The first argument to `date()` is a format string, the second argument is a timestamp.

Comment: What is `$info;` supposed to do? Just naming a variable doesn't initialize it to an array.

Comment: Ive named the array to be $info

Answer (score 0):

```
$info[3] = date($name);
```

should be:

```
$info[3] = filemtime($name);
```

This will set `$info[3]` to a numeric timestamp. `print_file_info()` needs to call `date_default_timezone_set()`, and then it can use the `date()` function to format the timestamp in the manner you want.

And to create an array, you need to initialize the variable:

```
$info = array();
```